# Does Git send out information over the internet?

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, git

If we install git on a server and use SSH protocol or HTTP/S to pull/push repo, Does it count like send out information over internet? How can I make sure that does not happen on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define how you want your software supply chain to work. If you don't want users going to github.com, define where the repos are going to be, and enforce that.

git remotes, like any other URL, can be local or on the Internet.

Controlling network access is with a firewall, like any other application. There are three network protocols available for git remotes, [http, ssh, and git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols). http and ssh are useful for other non-git things, but if the server has no reason to access the Internet, don't allow it.

In house git hosting is probably a good idea. Host a copy of repos, manage processes around reviews and merges, drive CI/CD pipelines, etc.  Software exists to help run a git server with these extra features.

Comment: Therefore it is required a ssh service installed to allow ssh Auth?, excuse me what do you mean by non-git things?

Comment: http and ssh are transports for more than just git. Blocking ports 22 80 443  potentially does more than impact git.  Nothing about git requires ssh, but ssh is very convenient for auth and transport.

Comment: Do you mean git itself does not requires ssh, but if I would like to use ssh for Auth and access the Repo I can do it. It will not cross the internet if we have a firewall. So, we can use it on the local network for a team to Co work.